# guardar borrados SQL consulta

Tags: sql

Tengo esta consulta:

```
DELETE SOV 
FROM [SolicitudVTP] SOV 
WHERE SOV.id in (
    Select SV.ID 
    FROM [SalidaVTP] SV 
    JOIN Solicitud S ON (SV.Id = S.Id AND S.[FechaCreacion] > @DATE)
    JOIN Solicitud S2 ON (SV.ReabastecidaId = S2.Id AND S.[FechaCreacion] > @DATE)
)
```

Me funciona perfectamente, pero como puedo hacer para guardar todas las ID's borradas? Para usarlas mas adelante?

gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo utilizar `INSERT + SELECT` en una tabla para ese propósito. Te quedaría algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE ids_borradas(
    id int
  );

INSERT INTO ids_borradas(
    Select SV.ID 
    FROM [SalidaVTP] SV 
    JOIN Solicitud S ON (SV.Id = S.Id AND S.[FechaCreacion] > @DATE)
    JOIN Solicitud S2 ON (SV.ReabastecidaId = S2.Id AND S.[FechaCreacion] > @DATE)
)
```

Podría ser interesante añadir un campo `DATETIME` para que supieras cuándo borraste ese registro.

Espero que sea lo que buscabas.

Comment: gracias!!! me funciona! ^^

Comment: ¡Genial! Aunque, ¿para qué quieres saber el ID si ya has eliminado el registro? ¿Por llevar una estadística?

Comment: Es un poco "peligroso" reutilizar ids que has borrado de una tabla. Más que nada por si tienes que ordenar por id en algún momento, el reutilizar ids puede devolver un orden de elementos no esperado

Comment: @Jakala, no me ha parecido entender que recicle los IDs, simplemente se guardan en otra tabla para saber que han sido borrados. Entiendo que el autonumérico siga asignando nuevos IDs correlativamente

Comment: Dice en su mensaje al final "para usarlas más adelante" por lo que entiendo qué quiere guardar los ids que ha borrado, para luego asignarlos de nuevo ( con lo que tendrá que tener un método para borrarlos de la tabla ids_borradas):)

Comment: quiero tener la id, para poder borrarlas de otra tabla que usa esas IDS.

Comment: eso ultimo suena mas a que te falta configurar los eventos de ON DELETE CASCADE...